# global declarations made available for all files as soon as the associated declared module is imported

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript 2.3.4, and I want to prevent **@types/knockout** exposing its global variable 'ko'. So I have put **types:[]** in the **tsconfig.json** and I explicitly want to import ko (like in second.ts).
The problem is that the import I do in second.ts is making available **@types/knockout** globals (ko, KnockoutObservable...) for the first.ts

first.ts:

```
const obs : KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable("hello"); // should raise error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ko'. and error TS2304: Cannot find name 'KnockoutObservable'.
console.log(obs());
```

second.ts:

```
import * as ko from "knockout"; // this import makes 'ko' globally available even for first.ts

export class Foo {
    bar =  ko.observable("bar");
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "declaration": false,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "types": [
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

The full solution is available here: https://github.com/kingatlas/typescript-sandbox

**How can I prevent ko from being global an keep using it as a module (import ... from)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way. [Knockout typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/knockout/index.d.ts) are following widespread pattern that allows to use them either as global or as a module. A side effect of that pattern is that variable `ko` appears in global scope as soon as knockout typings are included in the compilation.

One workaround is to compile `second.ts` and `first.ts` separately, each with its own `tsconfig.json`, and combine them later with bundler or module loader. To prevent `first.ts` from accidentally importing `knockout`, you need to have empty `types` and `typeRoots` in that `tsconfig`, and list all typings explicitly in `files`.

Another option is to make your own typings for knockout, declaring it only as a module. Again, you have to have empty `types` and `typeRoots` in `tsconfig` to prevent typescript from accessing 'wrong' typings in node_moudles.